# Why in python assigning one list to another and appending it also appends elements of both list?

Tags: python

1. 

```
first = [1,2,3,4,5]
second=first
second.append(6)
print(first)
print(second)`
```

output is:

```
first = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
second=[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

but,
similarly, if we assign a new value to the list why doesn't it change the contents of the first list like in the below example?

2)

```
 first=[1,2,3,4,5]
 second=first
 first=[2,4,6,8]
 print(first)
 print(second)`
```

output:

```
first=[2,4,6,8]
second=[1,2,3,4,5]
```

like in the first(1) example, why didn't change the element of the second list here in example(2)?

As mentioned in the above results why do both differ when assigned in a similar manner?

Comment: In the second example, assigning `first=[2,4,6,8]` makes `first` into a brand new list, with no connection to its previous value.

Comment: In the first case,  don't assign one list *to another list*. you assign one list *to the variable `second`*. Now both `second` and `first` *are referring to the same object*.  There is only **one list involved here**. In the second case, you do that to begin with, but then you create **a new list** and assign it to the variable `first`. Now there are two list objects involved. You should read the following: https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html

Answer (score 1):

In the first example (1), when you do `second = first`, both `first` and `second` refer to the same list object. Therefore, when you append to `second`, it also affects `first` because they are essentially the same list.

In the second example (2), when you do `second = first` and then `first = [2, 4, 6, 8]`, you are creating a new list and assigning it to `first`. However, `second` still refers to the original list `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]`. The change to `first` doesn't affect `second` because they are now referencing different list objects.

The key difference lies in whether you modify the existing list or create a new list and reassign the variable.

Comment: they are the same list, not "essentially" the same list.